# Uploading files from GitLab through CI/CD to Nexus Repository (Raw Repositories) using curl command

Tags: gitlab, nexus

I am trying to upload files into raw repositories created in the Nexus using curl command from GitLAB CI/CD, I am getting the below error :
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
argument '--upload-file'.

The same curl command when manually run from the command prompt it is working fine ( Files are getting uploaded).
I have tried even removing the alias in the power shell, but no luck,
Requesting you to help on this.

Comment: Can you post your curl-command?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -k -u "xxx:xxx" -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --data-binary "@output.zip" -X PUT https://nexus.xxx.com/repository/{raw-reponame}/xxx/{version}/output.zip
```

Version number can be change {version}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31143042)